# Not able to create mock class/object to replace the functionality of a private member object in my class for unit testing in gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a following class

```
#include "B.h"
class A{
    public:
        A();
        void Store(char* buff, int32_t len){
            if (!b_read){
                b_write = new B
            }
            b_write->write(buff, len);
        }
        void Read(char* buff, int32_t& len){
            if (!b_read){
                b_read = new B;
            }
            b_read->read(buff, len);
        }

    private:
        B *b_write;
        B *b_read;
}
```

B internally writes into a file (batch mode) and reads from that file(one record at a time). It does it in a time based format, i.e. say after every x secs.

I want to write a unit test case for class A and I think best way it to create a mock class for B(as I don't want it dependent on B and do time based operations) and where I don't have to create a file.

In my test I'll be storing store the data into a buffer and read from that buffer. However, I'm not sure how I can let my main class use and create object of my mock class B instead of original definition of B

This is what I've done

```
//Original class
class A{
    public:
        A();
        // I've created another constructor for this class.
        A(B *ptr){
            b_write = ptr;
            b_read = ptr;
        };
        void Store(char* buff, int32_t len){
            if (!b_read){
                b_write = new B
            }
            b_write->write(buff, len);
        }
        void Read(char* buff, int32_t& len){
            if (!b_read){
                b_read = new B;
            }
            b_read->read(buff, len);
        }

    private:
        B *b_write;
        B *b_read;
}
//New mock class B
class B{
    public:
        B(){
            m_buff = new char[1024];
            m_len = m_read = 0;
        }
        void write(char* buff, int32_t len){
            if (m_len + len >= 1024){
                return 0;
            }
            memcpy(buff + m_len, buff, len);
        }
        void read(char* buff, int32_t& len){
            if (!buff){
                buff = new char[10];
            }
            memcpy(buff, m_buff, 10)
            /*
            * Rest of the code handles shifting of the data and all
            **/
        }
    private:
        char* m_buff;
        int32_t m_len;
        int32_t m_read;
}
```

I'm not sure how can I make my original class use this mock class B's object rather than original class B inside my unittest (I'm using gtest, I' haven't included google test unit here).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating an interface `IB` and making class `B` implement that interface. Then, in class `A`, use pointers to this interface. That way you can change the implementation in tests and use the mock class.

One more thing. Since you are using `gtest` already, I would suggest you do not write the mock class yourself but use C++ mocking framework `gmock` (which is fully compatible with `gtest`) instead. Here is how you would use it in your case:

```
class IB
{
public:
    virtual IB() {}
    virtual void write(char* buff, int32_t len) = 0;
    virtual void read(char* buff, int32_t& len) = 0;
}

class B : public IB
{
public:
    void write(char* buff, int32_t len) override
    {
        // Your code that writes buff
    }
    void read(char* buff, int32_t& len) override
    {
        // Your code that reads buff
    }
}
```

Then, make a mock class that also implements this interface using gmock:

```
class BMock : public IB
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(write, void(char*, int32_t));
    MOCK_METHOD2(read, void(char*, int32_t&));
}
```

Finally, in your tests, you can mock calls to this function using `gtest`. This is what you would do in test body (written in pseudocode):

```
vector<string> dummyData = { string("str1"), string("str2") };
BMock mockObj;
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, read(_, _)).WillOnce( ... );
```

It can be a little difficult to figure out how to use `gmock` at first, but it definitely pays off in the long run.

EDIT:

If you are developing a performance-critical system and want to avoid virtual functions, there are ways to do that too. Please checkout the following links:

https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Nonvirtual_Methods

[C++ High performance unit testing with Google Mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424446/c-high-performance-unit-testing-with-google-mock)

Comment: `gmock` seems great, I'm not sure if I would be able to use it in this case, as I'll have to define my functions as virtual. Currently they're not virtual. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Raj Unless you are working on an app that will be executed on a system with limited resources, the overhead from using virtual functions is a small price to pay for productivity boost gained by using a mocking framework developed by google engineers. If you want to avoid virtual at all costs, please check my updated answer. Btw if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted as a token of appreciation for my time and effort.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tired upvoting the answer, but it seems that I'm not having enough reputation to upvote it. I've marked it accepted though. Thanks again.